# Android Sdk version upgrade

Tags: android, gradle

I am new to Android development, I am planning to upgrade my current Android mobile application to Sdk versionn 26.

The impact is there are several of dependency libraries are in the same older version as well.

I need some advise how to proceed with the upgrade, should I also change the gradle version?

I had a thought just to upgrade the TargetSdkVersion instead of the CompileSdkVersion, will that solved the problem?

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not updating `minSdkVersion` I would not expect any issues you can upgrade versions of `gradle`, `androidGradlePlugin`, `tools`, `CompileSdkVersion` and 'TargetSdkVersion`